# Erase all sheet

Tags: vba, image, excel, erase

I have a worksheet in a workbook were I put some pictures (I do not know how many), in a certain moment I need to erase all to have a blank sheet again, I want to make it with a  VBA macro, somebody can sugest me an easy way to do this task?

Thank in advance for your help

Comment: Please understand that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Therefore you need to show your effort, what you have researched so far and show the code that you tried yourself. It is very unlikely that people here do all the work for you if you did nothing at all. • A good starting point would be using the Macro Recorder, then do some research outgoing from that code and try to improve it. If you get stuck or errors come back with your code and ask a question related to it.

Comment: Thanks Peh, I have been trying with this:                                                      
    For i = 1 To 41
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    Next i                                                                                                          
 but I am looking for a solution without the limit because i am not sure about the number of pictures in the sheet. Thank for yor recomendation.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it is not a free code writing service.  And the OP did not demonstrate any attempt at creating their own solution.... but, it took me longer to write this preamble then it did to write the following code:

```
Sub EraseTheThings()
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shp.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

And if this saves someone from getting grounded or fired because they were ogling inappropriate images of the intimate variety then it is my civic duty to help this person in their endeavor at creating Parent/Boss button.

My civic duty sir!

Comment: Thank ProfoundOblivious I think your propousal will solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

if you have only pictures and no other data exist in the sheet then you can simply delete the entire sheet and create a sheet with the same sheet name. Else if you got some data into it, you can try the solution already provided by ProfoundlyOblivious

Comment: Thank Durgaprasad, I will try with this solution